# Contiguous Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the table that I am working with:

```
MemberID     MembershipStartDate           MembershipEndDate
=================================================================
123          2010-01-01 00:00:00.000      2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
123          2011-01-01 00:00:00.000      2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
123          2013-05-01 00:00:00.000      2013-12-31 00:00:00.000
123          2014-01-01 00:00:00.000      2014-12-31 00:00:00.000
123          2015-01-01 00:00:00.000      2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

What I want is to create one row that shows continuous membership, 
and a second row if the membership breaks by more than 2 days, with a new start and end date..

So the output I am looking for is like:

```
MemberID     MembershipStartDate          MembershipEndDate
=================================================================
123          2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     2012-12-31 00:00:00.000
123          2013-05-01 00:00:00.000     2015-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

There is a memberID field attached to these dates which is how they are grouped.

Comment: Without the memberID field in the sample data, there's no way for us to know why you chose to combine the records the way you did.

Comment: Added memberid, hope that helps

Comment: How does `123` have overlapping start/end dates? Ex: `2013/01/01-2013/12/31` & `2013/05/01 - 2013/12/31`

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the results either. Why are there 2 rows when there's no gap in the different overlapping start and end dates? There should only be one row.

Comment: Sorry about that, lots of typo's on my part.. hope it makes more sense now.. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This is actually a somewhat more complicated problem than it might appear at first glance.  Take a look at some of the answers on this question which is possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549117/how-to-make-calculation-on-time-intervals

Comment: If anyone gets a chance please upvote so we can get more eyes on this please.. I looked at some similar problems, but they don't exactly fit my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to deal with this kind of thing before
I use something like this

```
USE tempdb
--Create test Data
DECLARE @Membership TABLE (MemberID int ,MembershipStartDate date,MembershipEndDate date)
INSERT @Membership
(MemberID,MembershipStartDate,MembershipEndDate)
VALUES (123,'2010-01-01','2012-12-31'),
       (123,'2011-01-01','2012-12-31'),
       (123,'2013-05-01','2013-12-31'),
       (123,'2014-01-01','2014-12-31'),
       (123,'2015-01-01','2015-03-31')


--Create a table to hold all the dates that might be turning points
DECLARE @SignificantDates Table(MemberID int, SignificantDate date, IsMember bit DEFAULT 0)

--Populate table with the start and end dates as well as the days just before and just after each period
INSERT @SignificantDates (MemberID ,SignificantDate)
SELECT MemberID, MembershipStartDate FROM @Membership
UNION 
SELECT MemberID,DATEADD(day,-1,MembershipStartDate ) FROM @Membership
UNION 
SELECT MemberID,MembershipEndDate FROM @Membership
UNION 
SELECT MemberID,DATEADD(day,1,MembershipEndDate) FROM @Membership

--Set the is member flag for each date that is covered by a membership
UPDATE sd SET IsMember = 1
FROM @SignificantDates  sd
JOIN @Membership m ON MembershipStartDate<= SignificantDate AND SignificantDate <= MembershipEndDate

--To demonstrate what we're about to do, Select all the dates and show the IsMember Flag and the previous value
SELECT sd.MemberID, sd.SignificantDate,sd.IsMember, prv.prevIsMember 
FROM
@SignificantDates sd 
JOIN (SELECT 
      MemberId,
      SignificantDate,
      IsMember, 
      Lag(IsMember,1) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY SignificantDate desc) AS prevIsMember FROM @SignificantDates 
      ) as prv
ON sd.MemberID = prv.MemberID
AND sd.SignificantDate = prv.SignificantDate
ORDER BY sd.MemberID, sd.SignificantDate

--Delete the ones where the flag is the same as the previous value
delete sd
FROM
@SignificantDates sd 
JOIN (SELECT MemberId, SignificantDate,IsMember, Lag(IsMember,1) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY SignificantDate) AS prevIsMember  FROM @SignificantDates ) as prv
ON sd.MemberID = prv.MemberID
AND sd.SignificantDate = prv.SignificantDate
AND prv.IsMember = prv.prevIsMember 


--SELECT the Start date for each period of membership and the day before the following period of non membership
SELECT 
nxt.MemberId,
nxt.SignificantDate AS MembershipStartDate,
DATEADD(day,-1,nxt.NextSignificantDate)  AS MembershipEndDate
FROM 
(
SELECT 
MemberID,
SignificantDate,
LEAd(SignificantDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberId ORDER BY SignificantDate)   AS NextSignificantDate,
IsMember
FROM @SignificantDates 
) nxt
WHERE nxt.IsMember = 1
```

Comment: This is brilliant  and very easy to follow along.. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: For future people in my situation,  to the `JOIN @Membership m ON MembershipStartDate<= SignificantDate AND SignificantDate <= MembershipEndDate` add `AND m.MemberID = sd.MemberID`. Also, this is easily modifiable to work at the time level, just changing day for seconds and the dates for datetimes. As Herman said, this answer is brilliant, I couldn't have figured this out in a lifetime.